# Установление TCP соединения на Java

Tags: java, сокет

Кроме сокетов, есть ли в Java ещё способы установления TCP соединения?

И подойдут ли сокеты, если мне надо подключаться к стороннему http-серверу и выгружать с него веб-страничку?

Comment: 1. Есть. 2. да подойдут. 3. сделайте вопрос конкретнее. и укажите что вы использовали и как .

Comment: Да я как бы ещё ничего не начал использовать. А можете сказать что ещё кроме сокетов можно использовать? Просто гугл в основном только сокеты и предлагает. Я так понял, это наиболее простой способ.

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать HTTP то: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, а как ещё можно установить TCP соединение кроме как через сокеты?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю немного *теоретический* ответ, ибо, на мой взгляд, автор не совсем понимает концепцию взаимодействия открытых систем.

Советую вам на пару вечеров оставить в покое Java и другие языки программирования и прочитать ряд материалов про [эталонную семиуровневую модель взаимодействия открытых систем (OSI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI).

В Сети есть много информации на русском языке о модели OSI, а так же детальное описание каждого уровня. Коллеги наверняка со мной согласятся, что без чёткого понимания значения уровней и их роли в сетевых коммуникациях, вы попросту не сможете стать хорошим программистом, создающим сетевые приложения. Понимание модели OSI необходимо как базисту, так и веб-разработчику. Вне зависисмости от того, на каком языке они пишут.

После прочтения статей о модели OSI вы будете по-другому относиться к собственному вопросу. Вы поймете насколько *сокеты* (работающие в большинстве случаев на *транспортном* уровне) далеки от нужного вам протокола `HTTP` - протокола уровня приложения.

Comment: Интересно очень, почитал, спасибо.
Кстати, в классе `java.net.URL` есть метод `openStream()`, который возвращает `InputStream`. Я правильно понимаю, что он как раз мне и нужен для чтения веб-страниц?